# Swift lazy array with throwing

Tags: swift

I need to make a lazy array of my objects and process them later. For instance:

```swift
struct A {
    init(i: Int) {
        print(i)
    }
}

let arrayA = (0..<3).lazy.map { A(i: $0) }
print(arrayA)
```

Outputs:

```bash
LazyMapSequence<Range<Int>, A>(_base: Range(0..<3), _transform: (Function))
```

The code from above works OK - neither `init` are called. But it changes when I try to use throwing initializer:

```swift
struct B {
    init(i: Int) throws {
        print(i)
    }
}

let arrayB = try (0..<3).lazy.map { try B(i: $0) }
print(arrayB)
```

Outputs:

```bash
0
1
2
[__lldb_expr_92.B(), __lldb_expr_92.B(), __lldb_expr_92.B()]
```

As you can see all inits are called and the array is regular.

I haven't found any info about so my questions are:

- Why does `try` force to convert from a lazy to a regular one (No throwing enumerator for collection etc.)?
- Is it possible to make a lazy array with `throw`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple workaround is wrapping throwing creation of your objects with throwing closures to postpone initialization and then you can operate lazy array of closures:

```swift
struct B {
    init(i: Int) throws {
        print(i)
    }
}

let arrayB = (0..<3).lazy.map { i in { try B(i: i) } }
print(arrayB)
print(try arrayB[0]()) // Request first object
```

Outputs:

```bash
LazyMapSequence<Range<Int>, () throws -> B>(_base: Range(0..<3), _transform: (Function))
0
B()
```